# Python - access flask app context before serving requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Usecase: I have a python flask app that runs `background_function()` before serving any requests on routes.

When I execute the flask app, I receive the error - `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` I receive the error since I try to get the application context before any request is served.

What is the best pythonic way to execute the `background_function()` in this example?

```
from flask import Flask
from download import Download

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

# run backgroung function
Download.background_function()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The `config` file

```
FILE_LOCATION = os.environ['FILE_LOCATION'] # "file/path/on/server"

# Many other variables are present in this file
```

The `download` file

```
from flask import current_app as app

class Download:

    @staticmethod
    def background_function():
        file_path = app.config["FILE_LOCATION"]
        # code to download file from server to local
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask
from download import Download

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Download.background_function()
    app.run()
```

the `download` file

```
from flask import current_app as app

class Download:

    @staticmethod
    def background_function():
        print("testing")
```

given output:

```
testing
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

As you can see, the function runs first and prints `testing` and then runs the application.

Comment: Tried it. It did not work.

Comment: I have reworked the answer, let me know if that works and accept the answer if it does @here_to_learn